# Setting an API key as a header for a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, request-headers

Attempting to work with a Fortnite API (https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api) and it requires me to pass the API key in the header along with my requests. I've tried using .setRequestHeader but haven't had any luck.

```js
  function getInfo(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET','https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/ninja',true);

  xhr.onload = function(){
    if(this.status == 200){
      console.log("Worked");
    } else {
      console.log(this.status);
    }
  }
  xhr.onerror = function(){
    console.log("Request Error");
  }
  
  // Fake API Key
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","12345678910");
  xhr.send();
}
```

Hope someone can help and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
```

While you are getting to grips working with APIs, play with a REST client:

- https://www.getpostman.com/
- https://insomnia.rest/

They will help you see what these requests are supposed to look like. Basically, first figure out what the API needs with postman/insomnia and only after that you write your code.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This didn't work either, still getting the same error: "Preflight response is not successful". Thanks for responding though and trying to help!

Comment: Did you give Postman a go? Can you get it to work there? If not, fortnite's API documentation should have samples. 
If in postman it's working smoothly, open your developer tools in chrome/firefox and google the error you see in the network tab, you'll find the solution with that for sure! It's most likely something to do with CORS, which you usually solve with headers or with a proxy in case you have a setup that includes webpack. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For API Key authentication you would call it like this... .setRequestHeader "ApiKey", "MyKey".